# Run SparkSQL stage jobs in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am loading a text file:

```
val adReqRDD = sc.textFile("/Users/itru/Desktop/vastrack_sample_old.rtf")
```

and i am storing data as temptable

```
adReqRDD.registerTempTable("adreqdata")
```

i need to query above table

```
val alladreq = sqlContext.sql("select DeviceId,count(EventType) as AllAdreqCount from adreqdata where EventType = 1 and Network = 0 group by DeviceId ")

val adreqPerDeviceid = sqlContext.sql("select DeviceId,count(EventType) as AdreqCount from adreqdata where EventType = 1 and Network = 0 and PlacementId <> '-' and BundleID <> '-' and DeviceId <> '-' and IPAddress <> '-' group by DeviceId ")

val adreqPerDeviceidtoSpotx = sqlContext.sql("select DeviceId,count(EventType) as AdreqCountToSpotx from adreqdata where EventType = 1 and Network = 9 and PlacementId <> '-' and BundleID <> '-' and DeviceId <> '-' and IPAddress <> '-' group by DeviceId ")
```

As soon as my job starts all the 3 active stages are running in sequence, how can i make them run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use futures to have spark actions kick off in parallel. Something like this.

```
val queries = Seq(
  "query1",
  "query2",
  "query3"
)

val results = Future.traverse(queries)(q => Future({
  val queryResult = sqlContext.sql(q)
  queryResult.write.format...
}))

Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: after this how do i write each query result to a file

Comment: added an edit. Check out the spark docs on how to write to a file. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions